Missing song Information in flutter audio_service notification bar. "'appname' is running"
I can't seem to display the track information/metadata and control the seekbar in the audio_service notification bar. It simply says that my app is running.
In the process, I converted the mediaItem to an audio source and I think the media item contains all the relevant information such as title and artist name.
I'd appreciate any hints on what might be missing for the notification panel to display correctly.
(edit: the notification disapeared for a while and reappeared after adding a new permission in the manifest I believe, but the seekbar is still not responding)
Some of the audioHandler implementation:
  /// Broadcasts the current state to all clients.

  _player.playbackEventStream.listen(_broadcastState);

  void _broadcastState(PlaybackEvent event) {
    final playing = _player.playing;
    final queueIndex = getQueueIndex(
        event.currentIndex, _player.shuffleModeEnabled, _player.shuffleIndices);
    playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
        if (playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.skipToNext,
      ],
      systemActions: const {
        MediaAction.seek,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      },
      androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: const {
        ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
        ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
        ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
        ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
        ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
      }[_player.processingState]!,
      playing: playing,
      updatePosition: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
      queueIndex: queueIndex,
    ));
  }


    audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
      builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
      config: const AudioServiceConfig(
        androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.showcaze.channel.audio',
        androidNotificationChannelName: 'Music playback',
        androidNotificationOngoing: true,
        androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
      ),
    );

AudioHandler methods
@override
  Future<void> addQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    //passing the media item to the player
    final audioSource = _createAudioSource(mediaItem);
    _songQueue.add(audioSource);
  }

  UriAudioSource _createAudioSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    final audioSource = AudioSource.uri(
      Uri.parse(mediaItem.extras!['url'] as String),
      tag: mediaItem,
    );
    _mediaItemExpando[audioSource] = mediaItem;
    return audioSource;
  }


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Flutter forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.
